# Why does TargetRegistry::lookupTarget fail but LLVMGetTargetFromTriple doesn't?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++, llvm-c++-api

I initialize the needed architectures but when I try to get the target it fails, I tried doing in the C api and it works fine.

```
// this works
LLVMTargetRef target = NULL;
if (LLVMGetTargetFromTriple(target_triple.c_str(), &target, &error) != 0)
{
    fatal_error("Target not found %s", error);
}

// this does not
std::string error;
auto target = TargetRegistry::lookupTarget(target_triple, error);
if(!target)
{
    fatal_error("Target not found %s", error.c_str());
}
```

I use clang on Windows to compile and I am linking to llvm version 15.0.0git that I compiled myself, I also tried a precompiled version and that didn't work. My entire LLVM code is written in the C++ api and I don't think I can use the C api for the output so I need to figure out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

More of a hack than a solution. I wrote the object file emitting with the C api.
You can use the `llvm::wrap` function on your module and it will give you a `LLVMModuleRef` which you can use with the C api. I am guessing the reason it works is because the C api uses a DLL. The actual C api function itself is just a wrapper.